# How to setup a connection to VPN from AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn

I'm running an application in EC2 which needs to connect to an external service running in a VPN (a connection to third party network). I have the IP address and auth details (pre-shared key) through which to connect, but don't know how exactly to setup the connection. Do I need to install a VPN Client or is there any other way through AWS Console?

If you can share the steps/tutorial to set it up, it would be really helpful.

---

I've configured Site-Site VPN and can see two tunnels under the VPN Connection (both are DOWN right now). I've shared the VPN config file with the third party and they have asked my source IP address to be used for both the tunnels. I'm assuming the source IP will be the public IP of NAT Gateway attached to my VPC (since the servers don't have public IP assigned to them).

Comment: EC2 is on Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Site to Site VPN([AWS hardware VPN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html)) configuration from Amazon Virtual Private Cloud to your On-Premise Network which do not require a separate VPN Client. After the configuration, you can access the Server in the VPN from its IP range.

Following AWS User Guides will take you through to configure a VPN Connection. Basic configuration is straight forward and AWS will also provide automated scripts to setup configuration in your OnPremise network.

- General Introduction to VPN Options Available in AWS: [VPN Connections](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html)
- Guide with Details in Setting up VPN: [Adding a Hardware Virtual Private Gateway to Your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html)
- Step by Step Guide for Configuration: [Setting Up the VPN Connection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html#SetUpVPNConnections)

Comment: Hardware VPN is not really suited to connection to a third party network, which is what this sounds like.  There are some assumptions in that service that assume the external network is under common administrative control, and trusted.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it is indeed a connection to third party network. can you explain why hardware vpn is not suited for this ?

Comment: Hardware VPN assumes the other side of the connection is trusted and under your control.  It opens a hole into your VPC that is subject only to the existing NACLs and security groups -- it has no security groups or ACLs or route tables of its own.  It requires that your network numbering be compatible with the numbering of the connected network, because it provides no NAT capability. It is a great service for connecting to your office or data center, but not third party networks.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot understood. so anyone in the third party network will be able to see servers in my vpc (and potentially access unauthenticated servers). so what is the alternative solution here ?

Comment: Agree on @Michael-sqlbot points. Its a choice based on your scenario and security considerations to have a site to site or point to site VPN.

Comment: @Ashan I've configured Site-Site VPN and can see two tunnels under the VPN Connection (both are DOWN right now). I've shared the VPN config file with the third party and they have asked my source IP address to be used for both the tunnels. I'm assuming the source IP will be the public IP of NAT Gateway attached to my VPC (since the servers don't have public IP assigned to them). Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a VPN client in your EC2 instance but also can connect your VPC to the VPN server using:

- [VPN Connections](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html).
- [Adding a Hardware Virtual Private Gateway to Your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html)